# Unable to upgrade pip and requests modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests

I'm unable to upgrade `pip` from version 20.0.2 which comes default with the `venv` to the latest version of `pip` which is 20.2.

I've tried the following using Python 3.8.5:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate // in the venv now
$ pip install -U pip
```

And I get the following stack trace:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 357, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 270, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    skip_reason = self._check_skip_installed(req)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 246, in _check_skip_installed
    self.finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=True)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 898, in find_requirement
    best_candidate_result = self.find_best_candidate(
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 881, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 825, in find_all_candidates
    package_links = self.process_project_url(
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 790, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 497, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 337, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 126, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 405, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 51, in send
    request.headers.update(self.controller.conditional_headers(request))
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 233, in conditional_headers
    resp = self.serializer.loads(request, self.cache.get(cache_url))
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 97, in loads
    return getattr(self, "_loads_v{}".format(ver))(request, data)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 188, in _loads_v4
    return self.prepare_response(request, cached)
  File "/home/justin/Desktop/venv/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.12.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 140, in prepare_response
    return HTTPResponse(body=body, preload_content=False, **cached["response"])
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filter_status'
```

Same thing happens when I try to run `$ pip install requests`.

Any one have any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems pip had troubles with whatever was in my cache

Running this worked (for example):

```
$ pip install requests --no-cache-dir
```